# Front versus back in animal anatomy

Tags: evolution, human-anatomy, anatomy, embryology

Throughout various species, there seems to be a clear distinction between the front and the back. The musculature of the front, when engaged, closes or curls up the body, protecting it, while the musculature of the front straightens and stiffens. This feels intuitively to me like a pretty fundamental pattern.

Is this a "real" pattern at an embryological level, or just a common pattern of adaptation?

Is the innervation of the front and back musculature neurologically distinct in any way?

Which biological systems show a front to back separation?

How early in evolution does a front to back distinction occur?

Comment: I'm quite confused because the terms front and back are not very specific - it depends whether you're talking about front or back of humans vs quadripeds. For example, by front do you mean cranial (the head end) or dorsal (belly side)? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anatomical_terms_of_location

Comment: oops, that should read ventral (belly side)

Comment: @vervet I think the first paragraph ("musculature of the front closes or curls up the belly") makes it clear the question is about a ventral/dorsal distinction. I am not so sure about the clarity of the actual questions. What is a real pattern at an embryological level, what is a pattern of adaptation, and how do they differ? What is a "biological system", and how does one recognize a front to back separation in a "system" which is something else than one organism's body? The second and fourth points seem clear.